# What is the most amount of energy a super-futuristic humanoid could carry?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction

Imagine a humanoid character with limitless technology. What would they use as an energy source? Let's assume they can contain anything imaginable. Would them having a black hole core be the most energy possible?

Comment: Please see the comments on [this recently closed question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/238561/49261) to save everyone the time of repeating them here, the question is entirely unrelated of course .. but the issues with this question share **more** than a little of the same space  .. you may find it helps you better understand WB SE's ways if you take the [Tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) 

Comment: In it's current form this question is unanswerable. You're asking multiple questions at once, while not defining what *"limitless technology"* means in your world. Do you mean magic where literally everything is possible? Or do you have some other definition where there are restrictions on what is possible? If literally everything is possible then there isn't a most energy possible since E+1 will also be possible for any amount of energy. If there are restrictions we'll need to know those to be able to even attempt to answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

Black hole?  Black schmole!  Every super powered thing contains a black hole.  You can do better than some hole!

**Your character contains a Universe Seed.**

Before the Big Bang, there was a thing.  At, or immediately before, or immediately after the Big Bang, that thing expanded to the size of the entire universe in a trillionth of a second.

[What came before the Big Bang? UB physicist’s new popular science book explains one leading theory](https://www.buffalo.edu/news/releases/2022/03/033.html)

> “Inflation tells us that the period of time before the Big Bang was
> extremely cold, almost at absolute zero, and it was empty of
> everything but empty space, and that empty space carried energy that
> stretched the universe out to this enormous size and into the initial
> state before the Big Bang.
>
> “In order to explain the properties of the universe we see today, the
> universe had to double in size at least 80 times. That’s a lower
> bound, so you had to have at least that much doubling. To visualize
> this doubling, imagine a chess board. Place one penny on the first
> square, two on the next, and four on the next. If you continue
> doubling the number of pennies on each square, you will be a
> millionaire at the 28th square, and a billionaire by the 38th square.
> By the time you fill all 64 squares, you will be a trillionaire
> thousands of times over. Inflation involves at least 80 doublings,
> stretching a patch of space about the size of a grapefruit to the size
> of our entire observable universe in less than a trillionth of a
> second.

Thing which existed before this expansion were spread across the entirety of space.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflationary_epoch

> The rapid expansion of space meant that any potential elementary
> particles (or other unwanted artifacts, such as topological defects)
> remaining from time before inflation were now distributed very thinly
> across the universe.

Before expansion, the seed that expanded was one of several.  The others did not expand, and were spread across space with the expansion.  Each is the size of a grapefruit.  Your character contains one.  It is a relic of the time before everything.  Its energy cannot be measured.

It misses its siblings.